# Examples of non-measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm a newcomer in real analysis. I am learning the concept of measurable by myself using Royden's book "Real Analysis". I have a question regarding measurable sets. The following definition comes from Royden's book (page 35).

**Definition:** A set $E$ is said to be measureable provided for any set $A$,
$$m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^C)$$
where $m^*(\cdot)$ denotes the outer measure of a set.

To me, intuitively the above equation holds for all sets.
In $\mathbb{R}$, I think a set can either be an interval or a series of isolated points (right?). It seems these kinds of sets are all measurable by the definition. Can anybody give me an example of *non-measureable* sets so that I can have an intuitive understanding regarding this concept? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure that if you read a little farther in Royden you will see such an example. Be patient.

Comment: "In $\mathbb R$, I think a set can either be an interval or a series of isolated points (right?)."  No, even many "nice" sets are very far from this description.  I suggest looking up the Cantor set.  It is closed (and all closed sets are measurable), it contains no intervals, and it contains no isolated points.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I finally know what you mean. There is a section in this book talking about nonmeasrable sets. I didn't notice that before. The book is really splendid by the way.

Comment: [For the classic constructions](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/137949/8271)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no such thing as a *constructible* nonmeasurable set--that is, we cannot explicitly define one. We always end up relying on some choice principle. [Here's an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) to give you an idea of what a non-measurable set might look like.

Comment: Is the Cantor set a constructible set in the sense you mean here? (I know it has measure zero).

Comment: Absolutely. We can explicitly define exactly which real numbers are elements of the Cantor ternary set. Specifically, they are precisely the real numbers $x$ for which there exists a sequence $\langle a_n\rangle_{n=1}^\infty$ (with $a_n\in\{0,2\}$ for all $n$) such that $$x=\sum_{n=1}\frac{a_n}{3^n}.$$

Comment: Thanks. (You have an extra dollar sign)

Comment: No problem! (I was missing one, actually.)

Answer (score 36):

It is impossible to construct an explicit example of a non-Borel-measurable subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ as any proof of the existence of such a subset must require the Axiom of Choice ($ \mathsf{AC} $). As you may already know, any construction that relies on $ \mathsf{AC} $ is never explicit — $ \mathsf{AC} $ yields only pure existence results.

---

Before we go into a more detailed explanation, let us introduce some notation first.

1. $ \mathsf{ZF} $ — The Zermelo-Fraenkel axioms.
2. $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ — $ \mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{AC} $.
3. $ \mathsf{DC} $ — Axiom of Dependent Choice.
4. $ \text{Con}(\text{Statement $ P $}) $ — Statement $ P $ is consistent.

---

It is a well-known set-theoretic result (Theorem 10.6 of *The Axiom of Choice* by Thomas Jech) that
$$
\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZF}) \Longrightarrow
\text{Con}
(\mathsf{ZF} + \mathbb{R} \text{ is a countable union of countable sets}).
$$
Hence, from a model of $ \mathsf{ZF} $, we may construct another model $ M $ of $ \mathsf{ZF} $ in which the statement
$$
\mathbb{R} \text{ is a countable union of countable sets}
$$
is true. Observe that $ M $ cannot satisfy $ \mathsf{DC} $, for if it did, then as it is provable within $ \mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{DC} $ that a countable union of countable sets is countable, $ \mathbb{R} $ would be countable in $ M $. This is contradictory as it is provable within $ \mathsf{ZF} $ that $ \mathbb{R} $ is uncountable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176917/zf-every-nonempty-perfect-set-in-mathbbrk-is-uncountable)).

We now reason within $ M $. Let $ S \subseteq \mathbb{R} $; the claim is that $ S $ is Borel-measurable. We have, *a priori*, a sequence $ (A_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ consisting of countable subsets of $ \mathbb{R} $ such that $ \displaystyle \mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} $. Then
$$
S = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (S \cap A_{n}).
$$
As it is provable within $ \mathsf{ZF} $ that a subset of a countable set is countable, each $ S \cap A_{n} $ is countable. Hence, $ S $ is a countable union of countable sets. As a $ \sigma $-algebra is by definition closed under a countable union, and as singletons in $ \mathbb{R} $ are Borel-measurable, it follows that a countable subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ is Borel-measurable and that $ S $, being a countable union of countable (hence Borel-measurable) subsets of $ \mathbb{R} $, is Borel-measurable. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\text{Con}(\mathsf{ZF}) \Longrightarrow
\text{Con}
(\mathsf{ZF} + \text{Every subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ is Borel-measurable}).
\end{align}
We now see that it is consistent with $ \mathsf{ZF} $ alone that every subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ is Borel-measurable. However, this situation is inadequate, because without $ \mathsf{DC} $ in $ M $, we cannot develop much of real analysis, e.g., we cannot establish the $ \sigma $-additivity of the standard Borel measure.

If $ \mathsf{DC} $ is allowed, what are the implications then? This is explained in the next section.

---

Work done by Robert Solovay and Saharon Shelah has yielded the following result:
\begin{align}
& ~ \text{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC} + \text{An inaccessible cardinal exists}) \\
\iff
& ~ \text{Con}
(\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{DC} + \text{Every subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ is measurable}).
\end{align}
The forward implication was the first to be proved, by Solovay in his famous paper [*A Model of Set Theory in Which Every Set of Reals is Lebesgue Measurable*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m873-03/solovay.pdf). Shelah later proved the backward implication in his paper [*Can You Take Solovay's Inaccessible Away?*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760522)

One thing is now clear: If one wants a model of $ \mathsf{ZF} $ where $ \mathsf{DC} $ is satisfied so as to be able to do real analysis, and demand at the same time that all subsets of $ \mathbb{R} $ be Borel-measurable, then the price to pay is to posit that the existence of inaccessible cardinals is compatible with $ \mathsf{ZFC} $.

Actually, it is not entirely unreasonable to assume that inaccessible cardinals exist. In fact, modern category theory takes their existence for granted by postulating the existence of *Grothendieck universes* (a formal proof that the existence of Grothendieck universes is equivalent to the existence of inaccessible cardinals may be found in SGA 4, in the appendix *Univers* written by Bourbaki). Hence, let us assume, without losing too much sleep, that a model $ M $ exists that satisfies
$$
\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{DC} +
\text{Every subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ is Borel-measurable}.
$$

We can now demonstrate that any proof of the existence of a non-Borel-measurable subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ relies on $ \mathsf{AC} $. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that the proof does not depend on $ \mathsf{AC} $, i.e., it is provable within $ \mathsf{ZF} $ that a non-Borel-measurable subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ exists. Then as $ M $ satisfies $ \mathsf{ZF} $, we obtain (inside $ M $) a non-Borel-measurable subset of $ \mathbb{R} $, which contradicts the fact that $ M $ contains no such set. Therefore, $ \mathsf{AC} $ (or some weak version thereof) is indeed required for the proof.

Comment: Actually it is consistent *without* an inaccessible cardinal that all sets are Lebesgue measures. However if we want Dependent Choice to hold (which is a good thing if we want to develop analysis without worries) then you must do it with an inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I have incorporated more material so as to include Shelah's work. Hence, the latest version should be entirely accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Shiyu, 
If m* denotes the Lebesgue outer measure and if the measurability is defined as you did, what you obtain is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$ (a complete measure), which differs from a Borel measure. There are more non-Borel sets and a non-Borel set may still be Lebesgue measurable by a cardinality argument.

As others have pointed out, finding a Lebesgue nonmeasurable set requires AC. Many books in analysis have some standard "constructions" using AC. The following is my preferred method to obtain Lebesgue nonmeasurable sets and functions:

It follows from AC that the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ has a basis (Hamel). A set map from this basis to $\mathbb{R}$ would extend to a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This method produces infinitely many $\mathbb{Q}$-linear functions which are not $\mathbb{R}$-linear. An  $\mathbb{R}$-linear function from  $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ always has the form $f(x)=cx$. It is also a good exercise problem to show that every Lebesgue measurable $\mathbb{Q}$-linear function is $\mathbb{R}$-linear. Hence we have obtained many Lebesgue nonmeasurable functions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that the cardinal ordinal $c=2^{\omega}$ is the cardinal of the set $D$ of  uncountable closed subsets of $\mathbb R$ and that $c$ is also the cardinal of every member of $D.$

Let $D=\{E(x): x<c\}.$  For $x<c$ let $f(x), g(x)$ be unequal members of $$E(x)\; \backslash \; \cup_{y<x} \{f(y),g(y)\} .$$

Let $A=\{f(x):x<c\}.$ Neither $A$ nor $\mathbb R$ \ $A$ has an uncountable closed subset, so both $A$ and $\mathbb R \backslash A$ have Lebesgue inner measure $0,$ so $A$ is not Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: What is $D$? You define it twice and differently each time.

Comment: @Jethro. $D$ is the set of uncountable closed sets of reals. I amended the A for clarity.

Comment: But then you write "Let $D=\{E(x): x<c\}.$". Why can you define D again?

Comment: @Jethro . I'm not. I'm enumerating it.  $E$ is just a bijection or surjection from the cardinal ordinal $c$ to the set $D.$

Comment: Ok. Thank you !