# What is a everyday example of a non measurable set?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm working on my understanding of measurable sets and my immediate intuition wants to know what's not a measurable set? Initially I think of some space where divisions go to infinity, like a tolerance that just is defined to go on and on. For example plus or minus infinity from a to b would be unmeasurable. Does that even make sense? Furthermore measurable sets are topologies, which seemingly implies a very important property, because then one can find a defined function between any two measurable sets. In the end my biggest question is what's not a measurable set? Note: I'm learning measurability from the point of view a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Lebesgue measure is made this way. It should contain all "inuitively alright" sets.

Comment: Is that a Lebesgue quote?

Comment: Actually I think there is no example of a non-measurable set -- we may only prove the existence of such sets. See [Non-Borel set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Borel_set). Also see [Vitali set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: And [Examples of non-measurable sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226559/examples-of-non-measurable-sets-in-mathbbr)

Comment: No it is not a quote. But it is motivation.

Comment: Ok so a non-measurable is almost artistically abstract in a sexy pure mathematical way

Comment: Basically you"ll never run across a non measurable signal? Even uncertainty implies measurability but it's just uncertain.