# Can this set that require the axiom of choice be visualised as the limit of an infinite process (or some other means)?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice, quotient-spaces

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071939/) I sought a transversal of the quotient of $[0,1)$ by some [irrational map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation).  Really I was hoping for an explicit construction - something tangible which I could really get to grips with.

It turns out the transversal I sought to visualise is a Lebesgue-immeasurable subset of $[0,1)$, similar to $\Bbb R/\Bbb Q$ and the difficulties visualising it are discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/182247/334732), with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182265/334732) possibly some practical help but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/226562/334732) suggesting attempts for some explicit construction may be futile.

Until I learnt the above facts, I was hopeful a construction of the transversal existed which would not be entirely different to the classic construction of the Cantor set, which takes an easily-visualisable process and continues it to its limit.

But the whole "Lebesgue-immeasurable" property looks like a considerable fly in the ointment in that regard, since the Cantor set is of zero measure and therefore, I assume, an inherently different animal.

One of the matters covered [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/182268/334732) and elsewhere is that the axiom of choice is required in order to give the transversal the *linear order* it requires in order to be constructed over $[0,1)$.  Is that something of a death-knell for the idea of an explicit construction?

The quotient I'm working with, without getting into details, doesn't have a meaningful metric as a subspace of $[0,1)$ (as you would expect) but it does appear to have a meaningful topology as a quotient of a subspace of the lower-limit topology.  Is there still hope for an explicit construction, and does the topology sound like a reaonable "gadget" to use in the transversal's construction?  The topology does seem to be relevant since it gives hope to the idea of defining *least upper bounds* on chains, from which Zorn's Lemma can follow (thereby bringing the axiom of choice into play).

Comment: Every non-empty open set in the Sorgenfrey (lower-limit) topology contains a non-empty open interval, so the quotient topology is still going to be indiscrete (trivial).

Comment: Without the Axiom of Choice a transversal might not even exist!

Comment: The fact that a transversal might not exist is a death-knell for the idea that there is a construction.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sorry, could you please elucidate?

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott that is a huge help.

Comment: @AsafKaragila what I think you're saying is; I may not like the fact I can't define it without choice but I need to suck it up because without choice it doesn't exist.